# Equation involving exponentials $3^x+4^x+14^x=10^x+11^x$

Tags: exponential-function

The problem is to solve $3^x+4^x+14^x=10^x+11^x$ for $x>0$.

I have noticed that $x=1$ and $x=2$ are solutions; probably they are the only solutions, but I do not know how to prove it; I have tried some monotony and convexity arguments.

Comment: Is x an integer?

Comment: No; it is positive real.

Comment: Prove $14^x>10^x+11^x$ for all $x$ exceeding some $x_0$, then at least you have a restriction on the size of solutions.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Yes, indeed; one obtains that any solution of the equation is less than 2.42...

Comment: OK, so, at least we've ruled out any further integer solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An exponential equation over positive real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535196/an-exponential-equation-over-positive-real-numbers)